# how to solve first order partial differential equation in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the first order partial differential equation:

```
N0(t) + dN[N(d,t)R(d)/dy = dN(d,t)/dt
```

with intitial condition:

```
t= 0, N(d,0) = 0
```

and boundary condition:

```
d=0, N(0,t)=0
```

if someone know how to solve, can you please help me?

Comment: Please read [ask]. No-one will write your code for you.

Comment: http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/partial-differential-equations.html

Comment: 1) avoid variables like 'd': as you have it as an operator it will bring confusion

Answer (score 0):

try [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html)

Also:

1) avoid variables like `d`: as you have it as an operator it will bring confusion

2) make sure you have an **ODE** and not **PDE** (what does `dy` and **boundary condition** stands for?)